# Best Versioning Tools to use for Photoshop/Illustrator and related binary files?

Tags: versioning, photoshop

I previously asked about Version Cue 3 vs Subversion. I think this is a better question and someone suggested http://www.gridironsoftware.com/Flow/ I hope this question will allow others to join in and suggest other tools or give specific recommendation to using Version Que versus other tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://joshcarter.com/productivity/svn_hg_git_for_home_directory) comparing Subversion, Mercurial, Git and Bazaar for managing the files in a home directory, including image files and large Photoshop files that are being edited and versioned.

EDIT: The link is dead and I can't find the article, however the information in the article is now severely outdated anyway. Today I would strongly recommend using Git-LFS (Large File System), with the file locking mechanism that was added in 2017, I believe. This is the solution I currently use, as it solves both the problem of needed to lock binary files, and avoids the inefficiencies of git when it comes to storing large files - which was one of the main points of that article.

Comment: The link's dead. Per ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) this really should have included what the article _said_ and not just a link for specifically this reason.

Comment: @UrhoKarila The post has been taken down, but see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

[PixelNovel's Timeline](http://pixelnovel.com/timeline/) is a SVN plugin for Photoshop. They have standalone and hosted versions.

Comment: Photoshop plugin is very handy for our designers team. Even, if we would like to have something like this with git.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest https://www.pixelapse.com

It was made for designers with designer's needs in mind. Other solutions (GIT, SVN, etc.) cannot give you proper usability, and as well, your clients would be not able to comment, review and browse design milestones in an easy way.

Other way is to use https://layervault.com but they are struggling with some security issues. Also the usability is not really great.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Perforce ([www.perforce.com](http://www.perforce.com)), particularly if you are managing these files in the context of development projects. It is a code-oriented system, but it supports binary files well and has a Photoshop plugin. P4 isn't free, but it is worth every penny if you need professional-grade SCM - it is solid, fast, flexible and easy to use. (I am a very satisfied customer.)

Answer (score 1):

For my game development I found this: [Evolphin Zoom](http://evolphin.com) . It's pretty fast and it is compatible with all Adobe products. I like the Visual Asset Browser because it has a lot of ways to find things. It also has a web dashboard, which is useful if you have a team.

They are advertising it as a 'more than a replacement for version cue'. So if you're coming from that, you might find that a nice perk, too.

Comment: am i blind? where is the pricing on this site? or is this even free??