# Versioning for Websites

Tags: html, web, versioning

I am trying to find the best solution for versioning files on a large scale of websites, network drives, etc... shared among 40+ developers. We have roughly about 22 servers that each contain about 75 DNN websites hosted by PowerDNN. Common software shared among all developers are Adobe CS5 suite so I am not sure if there is something that even integrates into this software that would allow us to version. I am aware of a couple of the ones out there now (visual safe source, CVS, GIT) but not sure if these are the best solution for such a large amount of data. Network drives would contain PSD's, Text documents of site content, etc...

any help is appreciated, thanks

also something i forgot to mention, something that also allows to check in/out files for example a style.css for website 1 on server 1 is checked out then back in and a week later checked out and you are able to compare changes from last checkout and who made those changes

thanks again

Comment: Vaguely related question I have found useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186/best-versioning-tools-to-use-for-photoshop-illustrator-and-related-binary-files. Especially [this](http://joshcarter.com/productivity/svn_hg_git_for_home_directory) may be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Consider git at least if your files are mostly text and not binary (like psds and stuffs). Then you can create separate repositories for separate  projects and by doing this you should have no problem with the amount of data that you have.

Visual Sourcesafe and CVS are old (read: bad) and not as flexible and powerful as git.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Team Foundation Server. There are plugins actively being made to integrate TFS with other programs. Some plugins are free and some are paid.

http://www.codeplex.com/

Warning: TFS is massive and the learning curve could get steep.